# How can I change my JSON object with PHP?

Tags: php, json

I don't know any PHP but i need to get my JSON object to look a certain way

```
   $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => "look at this stuff",
        'sound' => 'default'
        );
    $payload = json_encode($body);
```

How can I make the JSON object look like

```
{
    "aps": 
    {
        "alert": "look at this stuff",
        "sound": 'default'
    },
    "view": "wc1"
 }
```

Comment: That JSON is invalid, you're missing a `,` on line 6

Comment: you're right. i hand typed it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to insert another value into `$body`?

```
$body['aps'] = array(
    'alert' => "look at this stuff",
    'sound' => 'default'
);

$body['view'] = 'wc1';

$payload = json_encode($body);
```

Comment: Yes. Thanks for the quick response

Comment: @softwareisfun: Great! If it helped you, please consider hitting that check mark next to the answer :)

Comment: StackExchange is forcing me to wait 10 min. (4 min left from now)

Comment: @softwareisfun: Right, forgot about that. Thanks!